# Guardar usuario de aplicación con trigger de Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

Quiero aprovechar la maquinaria de triggers que ofrece Oracle para crear una bitácora de auditoría de cambios.

Necesito guardar el usuario que hizo el cambio además de de la fecha y hora en que se hizo en una tabla `bitacora`.

Mi problema es que en la aplicación tengo varios usuarios, pero la conexión a la base de datos se hace con un único usuario.

¿Hay alguna forma de almacenar datos que no son propios de la tabla modificada? Estos se referencian con `:new` y con `:old`, pero el usuario no está en la tabla modificada.

Algo así como pasar un parámetro al trigger o que el trigger regrese el id del registro que acaba de crear.

Quizá que el trigger llame un procedimiento.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No podes pasarle parametros a un trigger, porque justamente los ejecuta la propia DB, no un proceso externo. Lo que queres no es malo, pero vas a tener que hacerlo de otra forma...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi por tu comentario. Como bien dices, tendré que hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: ¿Favor puede incluir en la pregunta la definición de la tabla (es decir columnas y tipo de dato)?